# What encoding does Marshal.PtrToStringUni assume?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, mono

I'm rather shocked that the [docs](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M:System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni) don't say.  It converts "an unmanaged Unicode string" -- but in what encoding?  UTF-8?  UTF-16?  UCS-2?  UCS-4?

I ask because I'm trying to use this to convert a CFString (on Mac OS), which I believe would be UTF-16, and I'm getting a garbage result.

Comment: UTF-16 is synonymous with "Unicode" in the framework, its what Encoding.Unicode is and is the internal storage format.

Comment: Good enough for me, thank you!

Comment: @JoeStrout Remember CFString is a struct ;-)

Comment: Yes.  All sorted out now.